# Saving another file with same name using django-storage and boto

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto, django-storage

I have a model `Profile` and an `ImageField` associated with it.

The images are uploaded to **AWS S3 bucket** for storage using `django-storages` and `boto`.

If I upload an image with a file name that already exists(`eg: sample.png`) **Django** by default would save the new file as `sample_1.png` which is not working while uploading an image to AWS S3. Is there a way to solve this issue?

How do I upload an image with an already existing file name to `AWS S3` without overwriting it?

Comment: Show the code that you say "not working".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given you've defined your bucket location in settings.MYMODEL_FILES_LOCATION you can use the following to rename the uploaded files in an arbitrary location, possible derived from the original file name. Following snippet would save the files in /mymodelfiles/.. The model instance properties can be accessed from the instance object in the renaming method, so you can e.g. upload files from the same user under the same subdirectory.

```
import uuid
import os
from django.utils.deconstruct import deconstructible
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings


def path_and_rename(prefix, filename):
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    filename = '{}.{}'.format(uuid.uuid4().hex, ext)
    return os.path.join(prefix, filename)


def get_path_for_my_model_file(instance, filename):
    return path_and_rename('mymodelfiles/', filename)


@deconstructible
class MyS3BotoStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    pass


class MyModel(models.Model):
    resources = models.FileField(
        upload_to=get_path_for_my_model_file,
        storage=MyS3BotoStorage(bucket=settings.MYMODEL_FILES_LOCATION))
```

Constructor of S3BotoStorage can take keyword argument "acl" to set permissions for the uploaded file, e.g. acl='private'